# How do i upgrade my Postgresql 9.5 to Postgresql 10 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I had a ubuntu machine on which postgresql 9.5 is running with approximately 12 GB of data. Now i want to upgrade my postgresql version from 9.5 to 10. I googled some articals but unable to upgrade and one more thing i do not want to completely uninstall postgres 9.5 and install postgres 10. My postgresql 9.5 settings are:

1-Postgresql config files are at:

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/
```

2- Postgresql 10 installed location

```
/etc/postgresql/10
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The normal process to upgrade on Debian or Ubuntu is this one :

Stop the new updated version of PostreSQL :

```bash
service postgresql stop
```

Drop the new updated version cluster to be sure nothing is inside :

```bash
pg_dropcluster --stop 10 main
```

Then data migration :

```bash
pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.5 main
```

Then stop previous version of PotsgreSQL :

```bash
pg_dropcluster 9.5 main --stop
```

Remove the old version :

```bash
apt-get autoremove --purge postgresql-9.5
```

Then just restart PostgreSQL, the new version with database migrated :

```bash
service postgresql start
```

Comment: First thanks for your response.So first i have to install new postgresql 10 on ubuntu machine and after that perform the answer scripts.

Comment: yes, that's the good way to do

Comment: can you please see my updated question.

Comment: In this case simply do as explained in the PostgreSQL documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html#upgrading-via-pgdumpall you dump your 9.5 database with pg_dumpall then stop 9.5 and start your 10 version and integrate your dump in this version with a simple /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -d postgres -f your_dump

Answer (score 10):

As already been suggested to use pg_clusters
There is no need to stop postgresql when updating to pg10

In Ubuntu terminal, Write following commands-

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main --stop
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main`

This would firstly install postgresql-10 on your system and then tries to update the server side postgresql using pg_upgradecluster

This would also solve your problem that you do not want to remove pg-9.5

Comment: sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main not working for me because pg 9.5 is located at /opt/Postgresq/..

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "unable to upgrade" exactly? Generally you can use [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html) utility to in-place upgrade. You need to have the old and new versions installed separatelly at the same time.

The pg_upgrade documentation I linked gives exact instructions.

Comment: by unable to upgrade mean i did not decided yet i had to install postgresql 10 on machine or something else